# Chart.js animate chart after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, animation, chart.js

I’m creating a radar chart using Chart.js. I want to start the animation when you click a button from the menu. Right now it starts when you load the site.

Here is the actual script:

```
var radarChartData = {
    labels : ["Html5","Responsive","LESS","SASS","JavaScript","WordPress","Git","WebGL","LAMP","CSS3","User Interface Design","SEO","Web applications"],
    datasets : [{
        fillColor : "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(250,250,250,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",              
        data : [100,100,80,80,80,70,50,30,100,100,80,70,70]
    }]          
}

var myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("skill-radar").getContext("2d"))
    .Radar(radarChartData, {
        scaleShowLabels : true,
        scaleOverride : true,
        scaleSteps : 10,
        scaleStepWidth : 10,
        scaleLineColor : "rgba(250,250,250,.5)",
        angleLineColor : "rgba(250,250,250,.3)",
        scaleFontFamily : "'Exo'",
        scaleFontColor : "#fff",
        scaleFontSize : 10,
        scaleBackdropColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)",
        pointLabelFontFamily : "'Exo'",
        pointLabelFontSize : 16,
        pointLabelFontColor : "#fff",
        animationEasing : "easeOutSine",
        animationSteps : 100,
        pointLabelFontSize : 10
});

var chartJsConstruct = function(){
//..your chart.js invocation with 'new' as shown above
new Chart(document.getElementById("skill-radar").getContext("2d"))
    .Radar(radarChartData, {
        scaleShowLabels : true,
        scaleOverride : true, 
        scaleSteps : 10, 
        scaleStepWidth : 10, 
        scaleLineColor : "rgba(250,250,250,.5)", 
        angleLineColor : "rgba(250,250,250,.3)", 
        scaleFontFamily : "'Exo'", 
        scaleFontColor : "#fff", scaleFontSize : 10, 
        scaleBackdropColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)", 
        pointLabelFontFamily : "'Exo'", 
        pointLabelFontSize : 16, 
        pointLabelFontColor : "#fff", 
        animationEasing : "easeOutSine", 
        animationSteps : 100, 
        pointLabelFontSize : 10
    });
};

var skillsLink = document.getElementById('ui-id-2'); // find the target to add behavior

// add behavior agnostic of browser
if (skillsLink.addEventListener){// for Non-IE browsers
    skillsLink.addEventListener('click', chartJsConstruct);
} else if(skillsLink.attachEvent){// for IE9 and below
    skillsLink.attachEvent('onclick', chartJsConstruct);
}
```

Comment: here it is http://alejuu.com/. What Im tryong to do is to start the animation when you click the skills menu, instead of starting when the website load.
Thanks

Comment: The chart is in the skills section

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have it. A bit of explanation about what I am trying to achieve here:

This constructor is what is responsible for configuring and constructing your Chart animation.

```
 new Chart(document.getElementById("skill-radar").getContext("2d"))
.Radar(radarChartData,{
        scaleShowLabels : true
        , scaleOverride : true
        , scaleSteps : 10
        , scaleStepWidth : 10
        , scaleLineColor : "rgba(250,250,250,.5)"
        , angleLineColor : "rgba(250,250,250,.3)"
        , scaleFontFamily : "'Exo'"
        , scaleFontColor : "#fff", scaleFontSize : 10
        , scaleBackdropColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0.75)"
        , pointLabelFontFamily : "'Exo'"
        , pointLabelFontSize : 16
        , pointLabelFontColor : "#fff"
        , animationEasing : "easeOutSine"
        , animationSteps : 100
        , pointLabelFontSize : 10});
```

Each time you call the above your animation will be shown. We require a reference to function that can call it each time without having to type the cumbersome string above. Javascript lets you do it by wrapping it in a function and creating a function expression like this:

```
var chartJsConstruct = function(){
                         //..your chart.js invocation with 'new' as shown above
                        };
```

Now you can bind it to any action in your code to run the animation like this:

```
var skillsLink = document.getElementById('ui-id-2'); // find the target to add behavior

// add behavior agnostic of browser
if (skillsLink.addEventListener){// for Non-IE browsers
   skillsLink.addEventListener('click', chartJsConstruct);
}else if(skillsLink.attachEvent){// for IE9 and below
   skillsLink.attachEvent('onclick', chartJsConstruct);
}
```

This should reload the chart.js animation everytime you click on "Skills" link. Let me know how it goes

Comment: @AlejandroJuárez If I open alejuu.com and copy the code the animation happens everytime I click skills link...Can you open your webpage and run that code in the console?

Comment: oh your right, but I already paste it inside the script that I created to load the chart , called radarskills.js and doesnt work also I try to paste in the head section, and at least I paste it in the chart.min.js and also doesn’t work, its weird

Comment: @AlejandroJuárez you can create a `<script>` tag like this `<script type="text/javascript">..put code here...</script>` and put code between tags....ensure that this `<script>` tag is defined only after `chart.js` `<script>` tags or you will see a bunch of `undefined` errors in the console.

Comment: Thanks!, I tried allready and the chart load but still doesnt do it when u click the button